# How to insert "empty" row into a DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, devexpress

I am using a *DevExpress* `LookUpEdit` control.  My database has two tables that control the population of control options.  One called MaintCategory and one called MaintItem.  This introduces a Magic Number into my program(the CategoryID) but allows for lots of runtime customization.

My problem lies in how to allow my users to un-select a dropdown WITHOUT me having to add an "Empty" Item for every `CategoryID`.  Isn't there a way to inject a blank row?  At the control level or when I construct the `DataTable` to return?

This is the DAL method that I use to populate all control choices.

```
public static DataTable GetMaintItems(int iCat)
    {
        using (var context = CmoDataContext.Create())
        {
            IQueryable<tblAdminMaintItem> tItems = context.GetTable<tblAdminMaintItem>();

            return (tItems.Where(item => item.CategoryID == iCat & item.Active == true).OrderBy(item => item.OrderID).Select(
                item => new { item.ItemID, item.ItemDescription })).CopyLinqToDataTable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could not get why you need to have a blank row. What do you mean by unselect dropdown "un-select a dropdown WITHOUT me having to add an "Empty" Item for ..."? Can you  elaborate the usage? For a dropdown, setting the selecteditem to -1 otherwise does the work.

Comment: @Kangkan:  Right now, once they select an item in the dropdown they cannot "change their mind" and decide they do not want anything from that category selected.  There is no un-select,clear, blank, etc option.  That make more sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I actually ran into a very similar issue in an app I was working on recently using DevExpress's `LookUpEdit` control -- the inability to revert the control to having *no* selection once a selection has been made.

My workaround was:

1. Set the `LookUpEdit.Properties.AllowNullInput` property to `true`.
2. Add an event handler to the `LookUpEdit.Validating` event.
3. In that event handler, check for a blank string as the `Text` property and set `EditValue` to `null` manually.

In other words, something like this:

```
void m_lookUpEdit_Properties_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m_lookUpEdit.Text))
    {
        m_lookUpEdit.EditValue = null;
    }
}
```

This allows the user to clear the text in the control, and have this effectively reset its value to `null`.

Answer (score 2):

I searched devexpress comunity content and found that it cannot be added directly in control.

But it can be done by manipulations with datasource.
I have found the example here:

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/AS13948.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
    dropdown.DataSource = GetMaintItems(x);
    dropdown.DataTextField = "Name";
    dropdown.DataValueField = "ID";
    dropdown.DataBind();
    dropdown.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select item", "-1"));
```

Thanks,
Flores

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately I am using a *DevExpress LookUpEdit Control* and it does not have an `Items`.